# Islamic academics/experts on the Bible especially in original languages?

Tags: christianity, islamic-scholar, bible

I'm looking for Muslims that produce scholarly literature (publications in peer-reviewed journals) on topics of Christianity and the Bible. I'm not really looking for a list of [Muslim apologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Muslim_apologists), though there may be some overlap. I would also be interested in Muslims that are experts in the primary original languages of Scripture, Biblical Hebrew and Koine Greek. [This list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_contemporary_Muslim_scholars_of_Islam) doesn't give any info on their area of expertise, and perhaps [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Islamic_studies_scholars) may have some.

Comment: What is your definition of Islamic scholar? Most Muslim scholars don't have any academic contribution as you seem to be looking for and even if they had they in first place wouldn't publish in English. However there are academic researchers that are Muslims and have a certain competence in these topics.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I would generally define a scholar as someone who provides academic contribution (i.e. peer-reviewed publications and academic-level books). What do you mean when you say "academic researchers?" I would be interested in who the Muslim academic researchers who have competence in these areas are. So all references would be appreciated.